# How to access the Text version of an Email Template

Tags: flow

I am trying to write a flow to add a task record after sending an email alert.  I would like to be able to access the same email template used in the alert via the EmailTemplate object.  However I can not find a way to access the text version that you can edit separately from the HTML version.

I am also looking to find out what the size limit is of the text variable in Flows. If it is 250 characters this could be a limiting factor.

Comment: Can't you access the Body attribute?

Comment: Yes.  I had tried this previously but there was not a text version of the template at the time.  Then I received errors in the flow because some merge fields available in the templates are not available to the flow.

Comment: Is this related to this known issue? https://success.salesforce.com/issues_view?id=a1p300000008XFtAAM (eg are you using Text Templates or Email Alerts in your flows?

Comment: Hello, is there any solution to this?